# How to mock a function which takes an object reference as parameter - google test

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I am trying to mock a function which takes an object reference.

```
class AMock :public A     {   
    public:

        MOCK_METHOD1(func1, int(Rectangle&));// func1 is a function of class A

        AMock(int i):A(i)
        {   
        }    
};

class MockService : public ::testing::Test
{   
    public:
        AMock* t;
        void SetUp()
        {
            t = new AMock(5);
         }
};

TEST_F(MockService, func1pass)
{
    using ::testing::Return;
    Rectangle rect;
    rect.set_values (3,4);
    EXPECT_CALL(*t, func1(rect).  //fails here with error
        .WillOnce(Return(0));
    ...//more code
}
```

Error - gmock/gmock-matchers.h", line 1022: Error: The operation "Rectangle == const Rectangle" is illegal.

Not sure what is happening. Although if I replace the reference by pointer it works. Like if I do

```
MOCK_METHOD1(func1, int(Rectangle*));
```

and

```
EXPECT_CALL(*t, func1(rect).  
        .WillOnce(Return(0));
```

Then it works. But the function signature of this class actually takes a reference.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to read up on gmock is the [cheat sheet](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cheat_sheet.md). There we find the documentation for the `Ref` matcher

> Ref(variable) : argument is a reference to variable.

The expectation has to be written with the help of `testing::Ref`

```
using namespace testing;

EXPECT_CALL(*t, func1(Ref(rect)).
        .WillOnce(Return(0));
```